# scrolling inside a particular div inside bootstrap modal not working

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

```html
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="choose-body">
  <div class="choose-my-connection" style="display: block;">
   <div class="choose-my-accnt-head">
    <h2>My Connections</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="choose-my-accnt-body ">
    <ul class="connection_list_tab"></ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Both of the javascript is not working.

```
$('#myModal').on('scroll', '.connection_list_tab', function(event) {
    console.log('post');
});

$('.connection_list_tab').scroll(function(event) {
    console.log('post');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `overflow:auto` for the class `.connection_list_tab` to make it scrollable. Now when you scroll the div, it triggers the `.scroll()` event.

```js
$('.connection_list_tab').scroll(function(event) {

    console.log('post');
});
```

```css
.connection_list_tab{
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="choose-body">
    <div class="choose-my-connection" style="display: block;">
     <div class="choose-my-accnt-head">
      <h2>My Connections</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="choose-my-accnt-body ">
      <ul class="connection_list_tab" >
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
              <li> asjkdjkasd </li>
            </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```